# Find an class a number of radio buttons in a div section then repeat separately for other div blocks

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find a DIV with a class of 'radior' and then find all the span elements I have inside of that DIV with a class of 'newone' and depending on how many 'newone' instances there are it will add a certain class to it. This is all fine but I want the function to reset after completing and find the next class of 'radior' and start again.

Currently what I have is adding up all of the instances of 'newone' and not per div.radior block.

```
<div class="form-group radior">
```

Option 1a

```
                    <label for="Option 1b ">
                        <input type="radio"> <span class="newone"><div class="moveme">Option 1b</div></span> 
                    </label>
```

Option 2a

```
                    <label for="Option 2b ">
                        <input type="radio"> <span class="newone"><div class="moveme">Option 2b</div></span> 
                    </label>
```

Option 2c

Here is a fiddle to show you what I already have:

http://jsfiddle.net/wwwredback/fsrLwzpp/3/

Any help is most welcomed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `jQuery`'s `each()` and `find()` methods?

You can access elements (`.radior` DIVs in your case) enumerated by `$(...).each()` via `this` in callback closure, and use `.find()` method to pick `.newone` elements, relative to that specific `.radior` DIV (currently you applying css classes to *all* `.newone` elements, not only under current enumerated DIV):

```js
$('.radior').each(function() {
    var ones = $(this).find('.newone'); // newone's of current .radior
    var count = ones.length;

    switch (count) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            var sub = ['full', 'half', 'third'];
            // important: 'ones.addClass(...)', not '$('.newone').addClass(...)'
            ones.addClass(sub[count - 1] + " col-xs-12 col-md-" + (12 / count));
            break;

        case 4:
            ones.addClass("quarter col-xs-12");
            break;

        case 5:
            ones.addClass("another col-xs-12");
            break;
    }
});
```

```css
.full {color:red;}

.half {color:blue;}

.third {color:green;}

.quarter {color:pink;}

.another {color:orange;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="form-group radior">
 
  <fieldset> 
   <legend aria-hidden="true">Legend1</legend>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="mainlabel" for="test1">Legend1</div>
    </div>
              
    <div class="col-md-8 
      
      required
     ">                           
     
      
      <label for="Option 1a ">
       <input required="" type="radio" tabindex="-1"> <span class="newone"><div class="moveme">Option 1a</div></span> 
      </label>
     
      
      <label for="Option 1b ">
       <input required="" type="radio" tabindex="-1"> <span class="newone"><div class="moveme">Option 1b</div></span> 
      </label>
      <label for="Option 1c">
       <input required="" type="radio" tabindex="-1"> <span class="newone"><div class="moveme">Option 1c</div></span> 
      </label>
                                               </div>
               
           
 </fieldset></div>
  
  <div class="form-group radior">
 
  <fieldset> 
   <legend aria-hidden="true">Legend2</legend>
    <div class="col-md-4">
     <div class="mainlabel" for="test2">Legend2</div>
    </div>
              
    <div class="col-md-8 
      
      required
     ">                           
     
      
      <label for="Option 2a">
       <input required="" type="radio" tabindex="-1"> <span class="newone"><div class="moveme">Option 1c</div></span> 
      </label>
            
             <label for="Option 2b">
       <input required="" type="radio" tabindex="-1"> <span class="newone"><div class="moveme">Option 1c</div></span> 
      </label>
     

     
                                               </div>
                   
                      
 </fieldset></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Ankhzet, of course, many thanks for your guidance. Perfect

Comment: "I know you’ll do the same for someone else" - MO of the StackOverflow =)

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your code lies in the statement  var `n = $(".newone").length;` here you aren't getting the span's with the `newone` class on a particular `div` you're looping using the `each` function so it is returning the total count.

You just need to find the span's in the specific div inside the `each` function and you can access the current `div` by using `$(this)` i.e. by using the `this` keyword in this way `var n = $(this).find(".newone").length;` you will get the correct span count.

Check the below code snippet. I've observed a few things in your code related to code smell and I'd like to suggest on a few things they are,

1. Your html is having unnecessary white spaces in the class names and your html isn't properly formatted it reduces readability of the code you can use a html formatter like [this](http://www.freeformatter.com/html-formatter.html) one.
2. There are unnecessary semi colon's on a function and on the else if block you don't need them on code blocks but they're missing at some places like on a click event you can use [JSHint](http://jshint.com/) to check the quality of your JavaScript code.
3. You've a little long if-else ladder going on, so you can use a switch statement to have better performance.

```js
$('.all').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('.selected').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});

function radioAddClass() {
    $(".radior").each(function() {
        var elements = $(this).find(".newone");
        var n = elements.length;
        switch (n) {
            case 1:
                elements.addClass("full col-xs-12 col-md-12");
                break;
            case 2:
                elements.addClass("half col-xs-12 col-md-6");
                break;
            case 3:
                elements.addClass("third col-xs-12 col-md-4");
                break;
            case 4:
                elements.addClass("quarter col-xs-12");
                break;
            case 5:
                elements.addClass("another col-xs-12");
                break;
        }
    });
}

radioAddClass();
```

```css
.full {
  color: red;
}

.half {
  color: blue;
}

.third {
  color: green;
}

.quarter {
  color: pink;
}

.another {
  color: orange;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group radior">
   <fieldset>
      <legend aria-hidden="true">Legend1</legend>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="mainlabel" for="test1">Legend1</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 required">
         <label for="Option 1a">
            <input required="" type="radio" tabindex="-1"> 
            <span class="newone">
               <div class="moveme">Option 1a</div>
            </span>
         </label>
         <label for="Option 1b">
            <input required="" type="radio" tabindex="-1"> 
            <span class="newone">
               <div class="moveme">Option 1b</div>
            </span>
         </label>
         <label for="Option 1c">
            <input required="" type="radio" tabindex="-1"> 
            <span class="newone">
               <div class="moveme">Option 1c</div>
            </span>
         </label>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
</div>
<div class="form-group radior">
   <fieldset>
      <legend aria-hidden="true">Legend2</legend>
      <div class="col-md-4">
         <div class="mainlabel" for="test2">Legend2</div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-8 required">
         <label for="Option 2a">
            <input required="" type="radio" tabindex="-1"> 
            <span class="newone">
               <div class="moveme">Option 1c</div>
            </span>
         </label>
         <label for="Option 2b">
            <input required="" type="radio" tabindex="-1"> 
            <span class="newone">
               <div class="moveme">Option 1c</div>
            </span>
         </label>
      </div>
   </fieldset>
</div>
```